# Glossaries Extra not generating Acronym List

Tags: texstudio, windows, acronyms, glossaries-extra, perl

I am trying to build a document using the `glossaries-extra` package. However, whenever I try build it with `\makeglossaries` and `\printglossaries` I get the following in my document:

```
"
This document is incomplete. The external file associated with the glossary
`acronym' (which should be called Thesis.acr) hasn't been created.

Check the contents of the file Thesis.acn. If it's empty, that means you
haven't indexed any of your entries in this glossary (using commands like \gls
or \glsadd) so this list can't be generated. If the file isn't empty, the document
build process hasn't been completed.

Try one of the following:

 Add automake to your package option list when you load glossaries-extra.sty.

For example:

\usepackage[automake]{glossaries-extra}

 Run the external (Lua) application:

makeglossaries-lite.lua "Thesis"

 Run the external (Perl) application:

makeglossaries "Thesis"

Then rerun LATEX on this document.

This message will be removed once the problem has been xed.[type=acronym,

title=List of acronyms]"
```

The `.acn` file has entries that are generated in it but there is no `.acr` file.
I am using TexStudio on Windows 10. Whenever I run the glossary tool I get the following message:

```
"Your document has used \makenoidxglossaries You don't need makeindex or xindy."
```

Even though I am not using the `\makenoidxglossaries`. I can successfully display the acronyms using `\makenoidxglossaries` and `\printnoidxglossaries` however I would like to use the options available with the `\makeglossaries` command. I have a perl interpreter installed.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}


\usepackage[acronym,toc=true,nomain,xindy]{glossaries-extra}
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}


\makeglossaries
\newacronym{ac:test}{test}{test acronym please ignore}


\begin{document}



\printglossaries[type=\acronymtype, title={List of acronyms}]

\gls{ac:test}
\end{document}
```

This does print the acronym "test" properly but the acronym error message is still displayed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hmm... well, if i change the `\printglossaries` into `\printglossary` your MWE (at least for me) work's fine and without any error-messages. So 1st question should be: will you get the error message again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Venez' comment I had a fiddle and realised that what was breaking my main build was that the `.aux` files weren't updating/being generated for certain chapters that were being imported with `\include`.
And the old `.aux` files had previously been built using `\printnoidxglossary`.
The reason they weren't updating was because they were being excluded from the build with the `\includeonly` command.
After removing this it worked fine.